# Are there any plans for site promotion at large gaming cons?

Tags: discussion

With Origins, GenCon, and other large gaming conventions coming up soon, it seems like it might be a good opportunity to expose large amounts of gamers to this site who may not otherwise know about it. Are there any plans to promote Board & Card Games Stack Exchange at these cons? Fliers, handouts, ads in the program guides, flash mobs, anything?